# Converting alphabetic compare function to a date compare function

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, date, compare

I am using a Mat List to display a lot of data. The mat list is used to order the data depending on the column values.

I have this working compare function which sorts alphabetic or numerical, depending of the input type:

```
function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

The table gets sorted by this function:

```
this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
        const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
        switch (sort.active) {
            case 'OrderId':
                return compare(+a.OrderId, +b.OrderId, isAsc);
            case 'Site':
                return compare(a.Site, b.Site, isAsc);
            case 'OrderDate':
                return compare(a.OrderDate, b.OrderDate, isAsc);
            case 'Email':
                return compare(a.Email, b.Email, isAsc);
            case 'Phone':
                return compare(a.Phone, b.Phone, isAsc);
            case 'FullName':
                return compare(a.FullName, b.FullName, isAsc);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    });
```

This is working as intended, however I want to sort the date property the same way, in a chronological way. How can I do that? I basically just need a working compare function, which supports 'isAsc' - is True for ascending and false for descending.

The a.Orderdate variable can be parsed to a date with

```
new Date(a.OrderDate)
```

Since it is a date converted to a string.

Comment: btw, your sort does not respect equal values. i suggest to use the return values of smaller zero, zero and greater than zero for sorting. then i would take the sort function and take a closure over ht wanted sort order.

Comment: in which form do you have the date? as iso or as epoch time?

Comment: '26-02-2018 22:51' for example. Can be parsed to a Date object if needed.

Comment: in this case, you could treat it as string.

Comment: No it will sort on day first, then month, then year. Normally you would want it the other way around

Comment: oh sorry. you are right, you need a wrapper for getting a comparable string.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171554/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-jonas-praem).

Comment: @JonasPraem—not reliably by `new Date('26-02-2018 22:51')` though, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)